# How can I run overleaf offline? Step by step

Tags: texlive, texmaker, offline

I have written all my thesis in Overleaf, but because I'm going to stay without internet for a while I need an offline option to run my project, which I have downloaded from Overleaf in a zip file.

Would someone explain, step-by-step how can I do that?
I have tried to download TeXLive but the online link didn't work, and the only file I could find on the internet is a zip file for TeXLive 2018, and I didn't manage to install that.

I have tried Miktex and TexMaker but when I tried to compile my project that I downloaded from Overleaf, gives an error:

> Log file not found!

I already have tried:

- Put MiKTeX in my environment path;
- Update MikTex;
- Change in TexMaker the compilation to LatexMk
- Creating a file in my project folder as described in: [Here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F)

Please, a receipt from all the programs I have to install, and how to install them would be great, to make sure I'll be able to run my project offline.

Comment: it is rather hard to understand your question, overleaf is an online site that allows you to run tex, so you do not want overleaf you want a tex distrubution such as miktex or texlive. You say you have miktex so that is fine. But you apparently have an error in your configuration locally but it is hard to tell what you have done or what the error is from the information given.

Comment: There is really too little information here to be able to help. "run overleaf offline" is impossible -- you can run LaTeX offline (overleaf runs LaTeX online). So if you install correctly Miktex and TeXMaker, you should be able to compile your project locally. Try with a small one (just an hello world) and report any problem here. (BTW, missing a log file is hardly an error, probably just a warning).

Comment: there are some notes on installing texmaker with miktex here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267756/do-i-need-to-install-miktex-on-my-system-before-installing-texmaker

Comment: step1: goto the page https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html and install TeXlive using instructions here. step2: use TeXlive with your project. If the step2 failed then try to find where the problem is or open new thread here and give detail description of the problem.